# How do I determine the necessary rotation of an object so that another dependant object is displaced where I need it?

Tags: vectors, rotation, geometry

I have two vectors, "V" and "W", that are attached to each other. If "V" rotates, "W" will be displaced in an angular fashion around "V". "W" has a fixed rotation, which I've set to 45º.

I've made a rough representation of this in MS Paint, as you can see here: 
[image: Rough Vector Representation]

Now, my end goal is to have "W" aim at a specific point, which can be anywhere in a 2D space, but by only rotating "V". Please note that I can only rotate "V", "W" has a fixed rotation, and the magnitude of the vector between them is always constant.

So, if I want "W" to point at, for example, "A", what rotation should I apply to "V" and / or what end position do I want for "W" in order to accomplish this?

*For optional context: "V" and "W" are Game Objects in Unity. "W" is a child of "V" and has a fixed relative position towards it. I can only manipulate the rotation of "V", which causes "W" to displace accordingly. "W" should be able to Raycast towards any of the objective points ("A", "B", "C" or "D") and effectively return a hit.*

I've searched for a similar topics, but they don't seem to address this specific issue (if they do, they're beyond my understanding).

Comment: Please clarify a couple of things. Are you saying that V and W are attached at the tail? Are you saying that W has a constant angle with respect to V? Do you only care about the direction of these vectors or is the magnitude of some importance? You say "the magnitude of the vector between them is always constant", do you mean "vector" or do you mean the *angle* is constant? This is not strictly a physics question but I can see that you're looking for the underlying math and if you can clarify what you're trying to do I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Matter of fact, scratch that, I believe I understand your problem now. Let me write up an answer...

Comment: Scratch that again. You said "W has a fixed rotation". Fixed with respect to what? with respect to V? With respect to the axes? Or with respect to the vector joining V and W? These are all very different questions.

Comment: @JeneralJames, thanks for your responses. I might be expressing myself incorrectly, and thus I apologize for that. To better visualize this problem, imagine a turret that has a single gun to its right (and a bit further in front). Height difference is non-existent, so only 2 dimensions are accounted for. I can only rotate the turret's base, yet I want the gun to be able to aim at a certain target, for if it's the turret facing the target, the gun would miss. The gun is fixed to the turret, and cannot rotate on its own (it will always face the same relative direction from the turret).

Comment: @EnzoFerber Yes, exactly. The "global" position of the gun changes as the turret rotates (akin to how a chained ball would be displaced if the object it's chained to rotated), but that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question would be better posted in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com as you don't seem to be asking a question about physics but rather how to accomplish something in a game engine.

Assuming that you know the angular offset of W relative to V, and have a way to determine the offset of V from a ray cast between its origin and the intended point. At that point you can now determine the offset of W relative to the ray cast to A from V's origin, so you can find the amount you need to turn V by to point W at A.
\begin{equation} \ O_{w,a} = O_{v,a} ± O_{w,v} \end{equation}
Where O represents the angle between the vector V and a vector cast between the point V and the destination point.

Comment: Ethan, thanks for this suggestion. While true that I want to accomplish this in a game engine, I am missing the underlying math, which is unrelated to any engine or code language. I tried to use abstract concepts to represent this issue, yet added the context just in case. Edit: I forgot to mention, I will post this same question there, as per your suggestion.

Comment: Alright, I'll edit my answer to include something, though that would probably be more suited to http://math.stackexchange.com as you want to manipulate a theoretical object rather than wanting to know how the physics of the system work.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. In order to determine if I understood correctly, I'll use some numbers as example. "V" is at (0,0) with no rotation (0º), while "W" is at (1,1) rotated 45º. The angular offset is 45º then, correct? Now, let's assume I want "W" to aim at a target A at (0,2). Is the offset between "V" and "A" of (0,2)? And between "W" and "A" of (-1, 1)? In your equation, would O(v,a)  be 0, and O(w,v) be 45, so I should rotate "W" by 45º? Sorry if I'm not expressing myself correctly, and thanks for your patience.

Comment: You can calculate the offset directly from W, though if you want to perform all operations on V that could introduce bugs later on down the line. And yes in that case the offset between W and A is 45 degrees counter-clockwise, so you would want to rotate V counter-clockwise by 45 degrees.

Comment: I think this might be beyond what I can grasp. I tried doing what you suggested (rotating 45 degrees counter-clockwise), but ended up with something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/DqZGNDs.png) - I think I'll just let this be for the moment being. You did respond with an accurate equation, so I'll mark it as the answer. Thank you very much for your time and patience!

Comment: In that case the problem is in what you tethered vector W to, which is definitely a question for gamedev and I hope someone over there is able to help you with fixing that issue.